# How to setup Xdebug in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: debugging, sublimetext3, sublimetext, xdebug, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using Linux 16.04, my PHP version is 7.0 and version of Sublime Text is 3.0. I followed few tutorials on the topic but none became fruitful to me.

In my case after pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + P</kbd>, choosing install Package when I search Xdebug nothing shows.

Any kind of suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I've found two xdebug packages in sublime-text

1. [Xdebug](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Xdebug) - Only for **Sublime Text** 2
2. [Xdebug Client](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Xdebug%20Client) - For both **Sublime Text** 2 and 3

So if you did not found any package suggestion then following could be occurred:

1. **Xdebug Client** May be already installed in your sublime text.
2. Make sure that 'Xdebug Client' is not in ignored_packages of your sublime text settings file.